# CS:GO competitive server: game ending before 16 won rounds

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, server-administration

I'm trying to set up a new CS:GO server to competitive mode.
However, it is not following the rule of 16 won rounds to finish the game.

This is my `gamemode_competitive_server.cfg`:

```
mp_afterroundmoney              0
mp_playercashawards             1
mp_teamcashawards               1
mp_maxrounds                    30
mp_halftime                     1
mp_timelimit                    30
mp_roundtime                    2
mp_freezetime                   10
mp_buytime                      45
```

Could anyone check and help me with that, please?

Thanks!

Comment: If you copied your gamemode_competitive_server.cfg directly into this post, there were some tabs in there. I don't know if those matter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what happened, but I copied everything again from gamemode_competitive.cfg and paste to gamemode_competitive_server.cfg and it's working fine now.